# How to change URL links of the buttons depending on what is selected in second drop down

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
<select id='A' name='A'>
      <option value='Andorra' selected='selected'>Andorra
        <option value='Switzerland'> Switzerland
          <option value='Wyoming'> Wyoming, USA
    </select>
    <select id='B' name='B'>
    </select>
    <div>
      <button onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';">Button1</button>
      <button onclick="window.location='http://www.facebook.com';">Button2</button>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
(function() {

  var bOptions = {
    "Andorra": ["A"],
    "Switzerland": ["B", "V", "G"],
    "Wyoming": ["D", "DJ", "E", "ZH", "Z", "I", "J"]
  };

  var A = document.getElementById('A');
  var B = document.getElementById('B');


  A.onchange = function() {

    B.length = 0;

    var _val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    for (var i in bOptions[_val]) {

      var op = document.createElement('option');

      op.value = bOptions[_val][i];

      op.text = bOptions[_val][i];

      B.appendChild(op);
    }
  };

  A.onchange();

})();
```

Based on what is selected in first drop down selection, selection options of the second drop down are changed. I need help to change URL links of buttons based on what is selected in the second drop down.

Here is jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/tcfsj2m9/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to jQuery this is extremely easier. First I'd change the `<buttons>` to `<a target="_blank">` tags so we can switch the href.

```
$("#A").change(function(){
 // remove all previous options for #B and reset your buttons
 $("#B").find('option').remove();
 $(".button-1").attr('href', 'http://google.com');
 $(".button-2").attr('href', 'http://yahoo.com');
 // Add the new option(s) to #B based on what was selected in #A 
 $("#B").append('<option data-button1="{the_URL_you_want}" data-button2="{the_URL_you_want}">The Value</option>');
})
$("#B").change(function(){
  // Add the new options to the buttons
  $(".button-1").attr('href', $(this).selected().data('button1'));
  $(".button-2").attr('href', $(this).selected().data('button2'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i need flow to be: select options in first drop down get options in second drop down, select options in second drop down, get URL on two buttons individually.